# How do you do a 301 permanant redirect route in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, http-status-code-301, routes

How do you do a HTTP 301 permanant redirect route in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: 302 is a temporary redirect ... 301 is a permanent redirect

Answer (score 8):

Create a class that inherits from ActionResult...

```
    public class PermanentRedirectResult : ActionResult
    {    
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public PermanentRedirectResult(string url)
        {
            this.Url = url;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
            context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = this.Url;
            context.HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Then to use it...

```
        public ActionResult Action1()
        {          
            return new PermanentRedirectResult("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }
```

A more complete answer that will redirect to routes... [Correct Controller code for a 301 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693548/correct-controller-code-for-a-301-redirect)

Comment: what if i am trying to redirect old .html files that no longer exist in the? can i use routing to handle these? What is the general approach?

Comment: I'd probably go with some custom routes like this http://blog.eworldui.net/post/2008/04/ASPNET-MVC---Legacy-Url-Routing.aspx or i better yet using a http module with a separate config so you can easily phase out and in. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx

Comment: There's already RedirectPermanent in mvc. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16980631/532517

Answer (score 2):

You want a 301 redirect, [a 302 is temporary, a 301 is permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx).  In this example,`context` is the HttpContext:

```
context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
context.Response.StatusCode = 301;
context.Response.AppendHeader("Location", nawPathPathGoesHere);
```

Comment: The first line is not needed, as StatusCode will set the appropriate label too. Status is deprecated.