# MVC RedirectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC can anyone tell me what `RedirectResult` is used for?

I'm was wondering what is the different between this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
}
```

and this:

```
public RedirectResult Index()
{
    return new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It is used to perform an [HTTP redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to a given url. Basically it will send the 302 status code along with the Location header in the response so that the client now issues a new HTTP request to this new location.

Usually you would use it like this instead of explicitly calling the constructor:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

As far as the difference between your two code snippets is concerned, well, it's more C# question than MVC related. In fact [RedirectResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx) derives from [ActionResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx) so both are valid syntaxes. Personally I prefer the first one as you could for example decide to change this redirect to return a view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

and if you have explicitly specified that the return type is `RedirectResult` instead of `ActionResult` you would now have to modify it to `ViewResult` (probably not a big deal but it's an additional step you have to do).

Comment: thanks , but i know that RediectResult derives from ActionResult but still is there is any different ? when we should retun RedirectResult instead of Action Result

Comment: `ActionResult` is an abstract class so you can never return it. You always return a derived class such as ViewResult, RedirectResult, JsonResult, FileResult, JavaScriptResult, ContentResult depending on what do you want your controller action to do (render a view, redirect to another url, return JSON formatted data, download a file, ...). As far as the signature of your action method is concerned I would recommend you always having `ActionResult` as return type for the reasons I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically both are same.Main concept is all results are derived from acion result.

So if in future ou wants to changes the return type then you can sill use action result.