# How can I redirect to either another view or an external site from the same action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Redirecting to another View returns an `ActionResult`.

Redirecting to an external site returns a `RedirectResult`.

How can I redirect to either another `View` or an external site (based on conditional logic) from the same `Action`?

What return type should I use?

Comment: Returning a `View` requires `ViewResult`. I think `ActionResult` already includes both of them, hence you may use `public ActionResult ...` and use if-condition to return either `ViewResult` or `RedirectResult` (but not all at the same scope).

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4387139/4868839) RedirectResult derives from ActionResult so both should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC RedirectResult](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387127/mvc-redirectresult)

Comment: In short you can return both using `ActionResult`, e.g. `public ActionResult ActionName() { if (doSomething) { return View(viewmodel); } else { return Redirect("http://path/to/external/site"); } }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `RedirectResult` or `ActionResult` should solve your purpose.

Eg:

```
public ActionResult RedirectMe()
{
   switch(condition)
   {
      case "RedirectOutside":
      return Redirect("http://byebye.com");
      break;
      case "RedirectToAction":
      return RedirectToAction("action", "controller");
      break;
      ...
   }
}
```